# how to write out a set of all divergent points of a sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Firstly, I'm not 100% sure of $\epsilon - \delta$ liked definition of $\lim_{k->+\infty} f_k(x) \ne f(x), x \in E$ where $E \subset \mathbb R$. The definition of $\lim_{k->+\infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in E$ is $$x \in E, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb N^+,$$ such that $$|f_k(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon, \forall k > N$$.

So by negation of proposition logic, I claim the definition of $\lim_{k->+\infty} f_k(x) \ne f(x)$ for $x \in E$ is $$x \in E, \exists \epsilon > 0,$$ such that $$ \forall N \in \mathbb N^+, |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon, \forall k > N$$. I think it should be correct.

And then I need to write all divergent points of a sequence of functions into a set. More specifically, suppose ${f_k(x)}$ and $f(x)$ are all real valued functions defined on $\mathbb R$ and all divergent points that $f_k(x)$ doesn't converges to $f(x)$ can be collected in a set $D$ where $D \subset \mathbb R$. My book claimed $$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{N=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{k=N}^{+\infty} \{x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$$ and didn't throw me the reason. It made me quite confused here. My opinion is by definition of $\lim_{k->+\infty} f_k(x) \ne f(x)$ for $x \in D$ , that is if $x_0 \in D$, then it should satisfy $\exists n \in \mathbb N^+, \epsilon = \frac{1}{n} > 0,$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb N^+, |f_k(x_0) - f(x_0)| \ge \frac{1}{n}, \forall k > N$ and I think $x_0$ should work for $k$ starting from $1$. So fixed $n \in \mathbb N^+$, I have $D_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \{ x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$ and then $$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} D_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{+\infty} \{ x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$$.

See it is very different from $D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{N=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{k=N}^{+\infty} \{x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your negation isn't quite correct. It should be: "for this $x \in E$, $\exists \ \epsilon > 0$, $\forall \ N \in \mathbb N, \exists \ k \ge N, |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon$".

Comment: @BolzWeir: Thanks. But how to correct it?

Comment: @BolzWeir: It is to say for each $N \in \mathbb N^+$, only one k work instead of all k, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that only one $k$ suffices to complete the job.

Comment: @BolzWeir: Make a great sense. I've posted an answer with your hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sincerely appreciate BolzWeir's comment.

I made a mistake on negation of proposition logic. The true definition of $\lim_{k->+\infty}f_k(x) \ne f(x)$ for $x \in E$ is $$x \in E, \exists \epsilon > 0,$$ such that $$\forall N \in \mathbb N^+, \exists k > N, |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \epsilon$$.

So fixed a $n \in \mathbb N^+$(actually fixing an $\epsilon$), then fixed a $N \in \mathbb N^+$, I can collect all x satisfying "$\exists k$"(all $x$ satisfying some $k>N$) as $D_{n,N} = \bigcup_{k=N}^{+\infty} \{ x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$. Then since $D_{n,N}$ should function for $\forall N$ $=> D_n = \bigcap_{N=1}^{+\infty} D_{n,N}$ $=> D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} D_n$, namely, $$D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} \bigcap_{N=1}^{+\infty} \bigcup_{k=N}^{+\infty} \{x: |f_k(x) - f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n} \}$$.